# Installing theme Ubuntu GNOME. Getting: "make: *** No rule to make target 'install'. Stop."

Tags: gnome, software-installation, themes

I've started using Linux in my own computer today. I'm running Ubuntu GNOME on a virtual box.
I wanted to install the [Arc-flatabulous  theme](https://github.com/andreisergiu98/arc-flatabulous-theme).

I followed their instructions but when I do:

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
```

I get:

```
[sudo] password for <myusername>: 
make: *** No rule to make target 'install'.  Stop.
```

I went back, downloaded everything I thought I missed but I can't get this to work. Can I install it directly though the files folder, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running `./configure` before sudo make install?

Comment: I ended up messing with my password. Had to delete the install. I'll try again in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `make` before running `sudo make install`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I think it does provide the answer. Note how these instructions for a different GTK theme have 3 steps instead of just 2 and the missing step is 'make' before 'sudo make install' https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/

Comment: Since you took the word "think" out of your answer, I'll retract the review critique.